# Keyboard Shortcut for context menu not opening for children Menuitems

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

Here is my requirement. Suppose this is the Application.

```
<Grid>
        <Menu IsMainMenu="True">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Exit"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit">
                <MenuItem Header="_Delete"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
```

Now when i press Alt + F the File Menu gets opened and when i pressed Alt + E it opens the `Edit` MenuItem whereas i want to open the `Exit` Menuitem in the file Menu.

[image]

[image]

Is there any way i could open Exit Menu on pressing Alt+F+E?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go to the exit menu, you can press: <kbd>Alt + F</kbd> and then press only the letter <kbd>E</kbd>.

This is because you already have focus on the menu strip so it will listen to single letters to go into the menu strip menu.

Comment: Yea but that was my requirement, i just saw on visual studio it works without releasing the Alt button

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)